# Generic Argument Error

Tags: c#, reflector, betfair

Hi im trying to fix this code in order to compile and cant find a way

ERROR:

> Pro\AGeeksToy\Controls\LadderHeader.cs(218,98): error CS0426: The type name 'menuData' does not exist in the type 'AGeeksToy.CoreDataTypes.AGeeksToyToolStripMenuItem>'

this is the error.

```
   private void ChangeStakingType(AGeeksToyToolStripMenuItem<EnhancedType<StakingTypeEnum>>.menuData newType)
    {
        this.StakeBox.StakingType.Value = newType.Data.Value;
    }
```

AGeeksToyToolStripMenuItem class code:

```
  namespace AGeeksToy.CoreDataTypes
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public abstract class AGeeksToyToolStripMenuItem<T> : ToolStripMenuItem, AGeeksToyMenu
    {
        public MouseButtons LastMouseButton;
        public MenuData<T> menuData;
        public static readonly VoidEventWithParam<MenuData<T>> RightClicked;

        static AGeeksToyToolStripMenuItem()
        {
            AGeeksToyToolStripMenuItem<T>.RightClicked = new VoidEventWithParam<MenuData<T>>();
        }

        protected AGeeksToyToolStripMenuItem(T obj, string text) : this(obj, text, null)
        {
        }

        protected AGeeksToyToolStripMenuItem(T obj, string text, Control ctrl)
        {
            base.DropDown.ImageList = IconManager.m_ImageList;
            this.menuData = new MenuData<T>(obj, ctrl);
            this.Text = text;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.DropDown.ImageList = null;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.MenuControl != null)
            {
                this.MenuControl.Refresh();
            }
            base.OnClick(e);
            if (this.LastMouseButton == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                AGeeksToyToolStripMenuItem<T>.RightClicked.TriggerEvent(this.menuData);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.LastMouseButton = e.Button;
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
        }

        public virtual void SetMenu()
        {
            this.LastMouseButton = MouseButtons.Left;
            if (this.MenuControl != null)
            {
                base.Visible = this.MenuControl.Visible;
                this.Enabled = this.MenuControl.Enabled;
            }
            foreach (ToolStripItem item in base.DropDownItems)
            {
                if (item is AGeeksToyMenu)
                {
                    (item as AGeeksToyMenu).SetMenu();
                }
            }
        }

        public T Menu_Data
        {
            get
            {
                return this.MenuObject;
            }
        }

        protected Control MenuControl
        {
            get
            {
                return this.menuData.Control;
            }
        }

        protected T MenuObject
        {
            get
            {
                return this.menuData.Data;
            }
            set
            {
                this.menuData.Data = value;
            }
        }


        public class MenuData<T>
        {
            public System.Windows.Forms.Control Control;
            public T Data;

            public MenuData(T obj, System.Windows.Forms.Control ctrl)
            {
                this.Data = obj;
                this.Control = ctrl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfUIA.png

Compile errors.

If anyone can download the project or check the source its available here

[Download Link Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/agt-betfair-bot/downloads/list)

Trunk available too but cant post direct link yet.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please, do your debugging and then come back to SO...

Comment: This one of the most useless questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are saying that you have a private void-returning method named ChangeStakingType that takes one parameter. The parameter's name is "newType" and the type of the parameter is `AGeeksToyToolStripMenuItem<EnhancedType<StakingTypeEnum>>.menuData`. But there is no type named `menuData` in your program.  There is a field called `menuData` and a type called `MenuData<T>` but there is no type called `menuData`.

Answer (score 0):

C# is case sensitive.

You are trying to use the `menuData` class, when the actual class is called `MenuData`.  Make that `M` uppercase